# models.py и views.py django

Tags: python, django

Создаю свой первый проект на фраймворке *Django* и столкнулся с проблемой. 
Создал модель в **models.py** и импортировал ее в **views.py**, в самом коде все написано верно, но отладчик почему то ругается:

[image]

Не могу понять в чем проблема? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models


class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=False)
    salary = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.second_name} {self.name}'
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp1.models import Worker


def index_page(request):
    all_workers = Worker.objects.all()
    print(all_workers)

    workers_filtered = Worker.objects.filter(salary=250000)
    print(workers_filtered)

    return render(request, "index.html")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вы пытаетесь запускать файл views.py напрямую?

Comment: по идее, на панель должны выводиться имена сотрудников из базы данных, но оно не выводится, я пока только учусь, делаю все по курсу, пытаюсь решить проблему уже второй час

Comment: Я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что курс говорил вам запускать views.py напрямую. Просмотрите курс ещё раз, там должно быть что-то про manage.py

Comment: действительно, похоже, что я упустил этот момент и все завязано на моей невнимательности, спасибо за выделенное время